# Value of type 'GIDGoogleUser' has no member 'authentication'

Tags: swift, google-signin

Im currently trying to switch one of my old projects from cocoapods to package dependency sdks and I get this error in doing so is there any fix for it? If more code needs to be provided i can do so but im just curious as to why this might be happening my assumption is my code is outdated but i dont know what to do to fix it.

```
//
//  AppDelegate.swift
//  Messenger
//
//  Created by Tooth on 6/6/20.
// 
//

import UIKit
import Firebase
import FacebookCore
import GoogleSignIn

@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

    public var signInConfig: GIDConfiguration?

    func application(
        _ application: UIApplication,
        didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?
    ) -> Bool {
        FirebaseApp.configure()
        ApplicationDelegate.shared.application(
            application,
            didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: launchOptions
        )

        GIDSignIn.sharedInstance.restorePreviousSignIn { [weak self] user, error in
            if let user = user, error == nil {
                self?.handleSessionRestore(user: user)
            }
        }

        if let clientId = FirebaseApp.app()?.options.clientID {
            signInConfig = GIDConfiguration(clientID: clientId)
        }

        return true
    }

    func application(
        _ app: UIApplication,
        open url: URL,
        options: [UIApplication.OpenURLOptionsKey : Any] = [:]
    ) -> Bool {
        return GIDSignIn.sharedInstance.handle(url)
    }

    func handleSessionRestore(user: GIDGoogleUser) {
        guard let email = user.profile?.email,
              let firstName = user.profile?.givenName,
              let lastName = user.profile?.familyName,
              let imageUrl = user.profile?.imageURL(withDimension: 100) else {  // Assuming dimension of 100 for the image
            return
        }

        UserDefaults.standard.set(email, forKey: "email")
        UserDefaults.standard.set("\(firstName) \(lastName)", forKey: "name")

        DatabaseManager.shared.userExists(with: email, completion: { exists in
            if !exists {
                // insert to database
                let chatUser = ChatAppUser(
                    firstName: firstName,
                    lastName: lastName,
                    emailAddress: email
                )
                DatabaseManager.shared.insertUser(with: chatUser, completion: { success in
                    if success {
                        // upload image
                        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: imageUrl, completionHandler: { data, _, _ in // Using imageUrl directly
                            guard let data = data else {
                                return
                            }

                            let filename = chatUser.profilePictureFileName
                            StorageManager.shared.uploadProfilePicture(with: data, fileName: filename, completion: { result in
                                switch result {
                                case .success(let downloadUrl):
                                    UserDefaults.standard.set(downloadUrl, forKey: "profile_picture_url")
                                    print(downloadUrl)
                                case .failure(let error):
                                    print("Storage maanger error: \(error)")
                                }
                            })
                        }).resume()
                    }
                })
            }
        })

        guard let idToken = user.authentication.idToken,
              let accessToken = user.authentication.accessToken else {
            return
        }

        let credential = GoogleAuthProvider.credential(
            withIDToken: idToken,
            accessToken: accessToken
        )

        FirebaseAuth.Auth.auth().signIn(with: credential, completion: { authResult, error in
            if error != nil {
                print("Failed to log in with Google credentials: \(error?.localizedDescription ?? "")")
                return
            }
            
            print("Successfully signed in with Google.")
            NotificationCenter.default.post(name: .didLogInNotification, object: nil)
        })
    }
}
```

I tried clearing my derived data and i tried rebuildingt he project as well as reinstalling the sdk